# Optimize for-loop with pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, loops, search

I have the following code:

```
auftrag = []
for datensatz_nummer, datensatz in daten_e303.iterrows():
    if len(auftrag) != 0:
        found = False
        for x in auftrag:
            if x[0]["Rechnungsnummer"] == datensatz["Rechnungsnummer"]:
                if x[0]["Auftragsart"] == datensatz["Auftragsart"]:
                    if x[0]["Mandant"] == datensatz["Mandant"]:
                        if x[0]["Unterauftrag"] == datensatz["Unterauftrag"]:
                            x.append(dict(datensatz))
                            found = True
                            break
        if not found:
            auftrag.append([dict(datensatz)])
    else:
        auftrag.append([dict(datensatz)])
```

In daten_e3030 there is a large pandas-dataframe, with around a half million rows and 8 columns, and in auftrag there is an list with sublist, containing the entries from the panda-dataframe.
For trial you can use these sampledata:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnRIWP-3awPOg9YD2oo_INQjCCq2PA?e=IsRayA

import using:

```
daten_e303 = pandas.read_excel("Demo.xlsx")
```

Do you have any idea, how I can speed up the methode from around 2 hours to anything below 10 minutes?

Thanks for your help,
Lars

Comment: You get a more quicker and better answer, if you provide the community with a sample data of your bigger dataframe. There would be a few people to put the time to go through your code and try to learn what you're looking for. Instead, add a sample dataframe, and aslo post your expected output.

Comment: @ashkangh thanks for your hint!

Comment: @LarsK1 Can you explain what this function does? Comparing the input data from xls and output, I see no difference.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely it reads the excel file, and then aggregates data from my invoice-system, which belong to one job. So it compares if invoicenumber and type of job and customer-id and sub-job-id are identical to any entry in the auftrag-list, if not it creates a new entry, else it appends it to the list which corresponds to the data added before. And the data written to the sublist is formatted as dict for easier processing afterwards ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody from a different forum gave me a perfect solution:

```
auftrag = []
daten_e303.Unterauftrag.replace(numpy.nan, 0, inplace=True)
print("Filtern nach Auftrag und Separieren")
for _, y in daten_e303.groupby(["Rechnungsnummer", "Auftragsart", "Unterauftrag"]):
    auftrag.append(y.to_dict("records"))
```